# Can't create Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

Trying to set up a Jenkins agent.

When I go to Manage Nodes > New Node

I only have the option to create a "Permanent Agent".
[image]
Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Do you just want to know what the "permanent agent" does, or is the setup not working at all because of some particular reason to do with that? The question conflicts the title a little and its not clear what you are asking to me.

Comment: I know what Jenkins does, and the purpose of jenkins slaves. When I go to create a Jenkins slave from the Jenkins GUI I don't have the option to create a Slave.

Comment: @randy I have updated to question if it makes it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting the Jenkins v2. You have to use permanent agents instead of slaves.
I haven't used it myself and only saw the [documentation link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slave+To+Master+Access+Control) about new slave to master access policy. But I guess it is the article you are looking for.

**Edit**:
The policy link is actually posted on Jul 06, 2015 and is not related to the slave/agent issue. Seems like slaves were renamed to agents [starting](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27268) the v2. I'm keeping the first link because it is still useful.